# Pipelining between two SEPARATE Powershell processes

Tags: powershell, pipelining

Let's say I have two PowerShell programs running: `Producer.ps1` and `Consumer.ps1`.

Is there any way to establish a client-server relationship between the two `.ps1` files I have?

Specifically, `Producer.ps1` outputs a `PSObject` containing login info.  Is there any way I can establish a **listener and named pipe** between the two objects to pass this `PSObject` from `Producer.ps1` directly into `Consumer.ps1`?

---

(**Note**: the two files cannot be combined, because they each need to run as different Windows users.  I know one possible solution for communicating is to write the `PSObject` to a text/xml file, then have the client read and erase the file, but I'd rather not do this since it exposes the credentials. I'm open to whatever suggestions you have)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I found this link that describes how to do what you're requesting:
https://gbegerow.wordpress.com/2012/04/09/interprocess-communication-in-powershell/

I tested it and I was able to pass data between two separate Powershell sessions.

Server Side:

```
$pipe=new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream("\\.\pipe\Wulf");
'Created server side of "\\.\pipe\Wulf"'
$pipe.WaitForConnection(); 

$sr = new-object System.IO.StreamReader($pipe); 
while (($cmd= $sr.ReadLine()) -ne 'exit') 
{
 $cmd
}; 

$sr.Dispose();
$pipe.Dispose();
```

Client Side:

```
$pipe = new-object System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream("\\.\pipe\Wulf");
 $pipe.Connect(); 

$sw = new-object System.IO.StreamWriter($pipe);
$sw.WriteLine("Go"); 
$sw.WriteLine("start abc 123"); 
$sw.WriteLine('exit'); 

$sw.Dispose(); 
$pipe.Dispose();
```

Comment: This is a great find and exactly what I'm looking to do. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Clarification for future readers:  **Server Side** is the listener, and **Client Side** is the producer.  In this case, the client is sending the message, through the pipe, to the server.