Is there a way to send character strings between 2 powershell terminal windows?
In unix world we have always been able to send character strings between terminal windows using the /dev/ttyS serial devices or the /dev/pty pseudo-terminals. To do that is trivial once you know your tty/pty number, and could use:
# On /dev/pty1 write:
echo -e "\nHello! \n" >/dev/pty0

# On /dev/pty0, receive:

Hello! 

(There is a bug in the Cygwin/Bash version that interferes with the character \n and whatever is in front, unless its a space.)
This even works in MSYS/Cygwin.
Is there a way to accomplish a way to do the same (in Windows) between powershell terminal windows?

I have seen that you can send strings using the COM serial devices, using something like:
echo "Hello!" > \\.\COM3\

But AFAIK, the Windows terminal shell doesn't have an associated COM port, nor anything else obvious or accessible.
Apparently the COM ports are set in the registry at:
HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\COM Name Arbiter\Devices
References:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/windows-command-line-introducing-the-windows-pseudo-console-conpty/#what-no-windows-pseudo-console

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/creating-a-pseudoconsole-session



Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/a/32057161/15339544

That is a very interesting find, but not quite. Because it requires you to keep something running (the while loop) on the other end, waiting for data. If there were a way to get this directly into the output buffer of the pipe, maybe it could be useful. I think this solution would require a some kind of asynchronous event handler and delegate, so that the other end can do other things and doesn't need to sit around and wait for data. At the end of the day, I just want to inject (in a lack for better word) a string into the screen text buffer on the other end, as it's done in *nix OS.

Set up the listener on a different thread, that class has async counterparts... you can also start the process in a different runspace and hook the output to your $Host or subscribe to DataAdding

@SantiagoSquarzon I'm afraid that is way beyond my skills. Any idea where/how to get started?

The simplest way to go is using Start-ThreadJob you can run that code linked in the answer as a task. Another approach more complex but also more customizable is to use a runspace to start the listener. Then that runspace is hooked to collection streams called PSDataCollection<T> and that collection has a DataAdding event you can subscribe to

Like I said, that is currently above my head. No idea how to do that.

The closest I could think is to use NamedPipeServerStream and NamedPipeClientStream as suggested in this answer, however the difference here is that your server is started on a different thread and writes to your console using PSConsoleReadLine.Insert, this provides similar functionality as what you have in the Linux word.
Here you can see how to use these functions:

You can also pipe to the writing function, so something like this can work:
PS \> Get-Content foo.txt | pipemsg theDestinationPipe

You should note using PSConsoleReadLine.Insert like this is a bit wonky and outside the supported realm.
Lastly, the Start-NamedPipeServer function outputs an object that can be used as argument to Remove-NamedPipeServer. Once you're done using your server you can dispose it like this:
# create
$server = Start-NamedPipeServer myServer
# dispose
$server | Remove-NamedPipeServer

Here is the function definitions:
function Start-NamedPipeServer {
    [Alias('pipeserver')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Name
    )

    if ([System.IO.File]::Exists("\\.\pipe\$Name")) {
        $err = [System.Management.Automation.ErrorRecord]::new(
            [System.IO.IOException]::new("A pipe already exists with name '$Name'."),
            'PipeExists',
            [System.Management.Automation.ErrorCategory]::OpenError,
            $null)

        $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($err)
    }

    $script = {
        while (-not $token.IsCancellationRequested) {
            try {
                $pipe = [System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeServerStream]::new(
                    $Name, [System.IO.Pipes.PipeDirection]::InOut, 1,
                    [System.IO.Pipes.PipeTransmissionMode]::Byte,
                    [System.IO.Pipes.PipeOptions]::Asynchronous)

                $task = $pipe.WaitForConnectionAsync($token)
                while (-not $task.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(200)) { }
                $null = $task.GetAwaiter().GetResult()
                $sr = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($pipe)
                while ($null -ne ($msg = $sr.ReadLine())) {
                    [Microsoft.PowerShell.PSConsoleReadLine]::Insert($msg + "`n")
                }
            }
            catch [System.OperationCanceledException] {
                # ignore
            }
            finally {
                if ($pipe) { $pipe.Dispose() }
                if ($sr) { $sr.Dispose() }
            }
        }
    }

    $src = [System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource]::new()
    $ps = [powershell]::Create().AddScript($script)
    $ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('Name', $Name)
    $ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('token', $src.Token)

    [pscustomobject]@{
        TokenSource = $src
        Instance    = $ps
        Async       = $ps.BeginInvoke()
    }
}

function Write-PipeMessage {
    [Alias('pipemsg')]
    param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory)]
        [string] $Name,

        [Parameter(ValueFromPipeline, ValueFromRemainingArguments)]
        [string[]] $Message
    )

    begin {
        try {
            $pipe = [System.IO.Pipes.NamedPipeClientStream]::new($Name)
            $task = $pipe.ConnectAsync()
            while (-not $task.Wait(200)) { }
            $sw = [System.IO.StreamWriter]::new($pipe)
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.ThrowTerminatingError($_)
        }
    }
    process {
        foreach ($msg in $Message) {
            $sw.WriteLine($msg)
        }
    }
    end {
        $sw.Dispose()
        $pipe.Dispose()
    }
}

function Remove-NamedPipeServer {
    param([Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline)] $Server)

    process {
        try {
            $Server.TokenSource.Cancel()
            $Server.TokenSource.Dispose()
            $Server.Instance.EndInvoke($Server.Async)
            if ($Server.Instance.HadErrors) {
                foreach ($err in $Server.Instance.Streams.Error) {
                    $PSCmdlet.WriteError($err)
                }
            }
            $Server.Instance.Dispose()
        }
        catch {
            $PSCmdlet.WriteError($_)
        }
    }
}


This is awesome! Works great. I added it into function in $PROFILE to auto-assign the $pipeName to be pty<n> for the current pwsh instance, and saving ptyN to the environment variable TTY. However, I am not able to save the $pipeHandle (what you call $server above) into and $env:TTYHAND variable. (a) Any idea how to do that?
(b) Also, what happens if you don't dispose the pipe server, and prematurely leave the shell? Does that leave the pipe hanging? (c) I see there are also name-less pipes, but not able to find out more. (ls -Force '\\.\pipe\*') Any ideas?

@not2qubit $server is a complex object, can't save into an env: var which only allows strings. If you close your shell then the pipe is gone, no need to worry about that. no idea about name-less pipes, you probably mean anonymous pipe

I see, so there is no way to make that complex object available outside current process? But I guess I don't really need it anyway. Where can I best learn more about Windows anonymous (and named) pipes?

@not2qubit no, you can't have that object available in a different process. at best you could serialize it and deserialize it in a different process but it would be just a copy of that object. best place to learn are the .NET docs

@not2qubit i updated the code a bit, recommend you to use this version than the older one

Do you mind saying a few words why the change? I see you removed something called [runspacefactory] and added some $token. I don't understand what that token does, and don't see it defined anywhere.

@not2qubit token is defined in $src = [System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource]::new() and passed-in to the runspace thru the proxy on $ps.Runspace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable('token', $src.Token). This approach is simpler and doesnt require an event to restart the listener.
